# Need to render a joomla component view on every page

Tags: joomla, components

I am really new to Joomla and can't solve the following problem:

I have a component installed which renders a small form. I can create a menu, and create a menu element which links to the component view (some links from the component appear and I just have to select them).

The problem is that I need that form to be rendered on every site page and after trying many solutions I still haven't found any reliable solution to do so.

Comment: write a `module`, assign it to a position on your template and let it show on `all pages`.

Comment: It is a purchased component, not a custom development.

Comment: For anyone interested, I ended up finding a solution: Installing Components everywhere (a free extension), I could render the component view inside a custom HTML Module, and print it on every page. I do not know why the question is marked as too broad, since I finally answered myself with a few lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually each page can render one specific component so for example if you mean rendering your component on page than show single article( that use com_content component ) you can't. see if your component have any module and use it for those situations

Comment: It doesn't have any modules, so in the end there is no way to display it the way we want, the only way is with an iFrame and it is not really a clean solution.

Comment: I see. Then the developer's support would be the right address.